# Parsing csv which contains json

Tags: json, csv, parsing

I have a quite small csv (120mb).

One of the columns contains a json strings which look like this.

`{"A":"Dart","B":"en","C":"[gb]","D":"4,5,7","E":"2019-03-07"}`

I need to parse this json from a csv and convert it to data frame or another csv which will contain A/B/C/D/E columns and corresponding values in a rows.

I've tried to parse it with python and pandas, using different libraries but without any luck, data always seem to be corrupted.

I've looked into raw text view of my csv and found out that raw data looks like this and it seems like parsers cannot chew it for some reason.

`"{""A"":""Dart"",""B"":""en"",""C"":""[gb]"",""D"":""4,5,7"",""E"":""2019-03-07""}"`

Comment: Seems like `"` gets encoded to  `""`

Comment: Do the parsers you have tried have a parameter you can set to tell them that the fields have values enclosed in quotes?

Comment: @tilz0R That is the standard way of putting double-quotes in CSV data when the field is enclosed in double-quotes to enable the use of commas inside it.

Answer (score 0):

if you share a source file, it could be simpler to help you.
That is the standard way of putting double-quotes in CSV.

I'm inserting an example on how to have the output you want. I'm using Miller (http://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/).

Using

```
echo '"{""A"":""Dart"",""B"":""en"",""C"":""[gb]"",""D"":""4,5,7"",""E"":""2019-03-07""}"' | \
mlr --c2n --implicit-csv-header cat | \
mlr --j2c cat
```

You will have

```
A,B,C,D,E
Dart,en,[gb],"4,5,7",2019-03-07
```